# php password update on mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to enable users to change their password.

I keep getting the user name and password are not in the file and I suspect the password is not correctly readable by the script, maybe because of the md5 encryption.  Is there any error on my SQL query?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE name='$e' AND pass='".md5($p)."'";   
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query. ".mysql_error());
    $num = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

Comment: No, there does not appear to be an error in your SQL.  If you are trying to recover the user's password, then you are right - the use of `md5` makes that impossible (but anyway you don't *want* ro recover the user's password - if they've forgotten it, just enable them to set a new one instead).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of building up your query with concatenation, you should look into using [PHP Data Objects (PDO)](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/).

Not only will it likely fix your error, it will also fix your current [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerability.